# Android Syntax Error (Code 1) SQLite rawquery problems when adding Where clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Cant seem to figure out whats wrong with my query statement, according to examples raw query's to sqlite this is how it should look:

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().
rawQuery("select * from todo where _id = ?", new String[] { id });
```

Ok easy enough, so I am trying to do this:

```
String query = "SELECT RESULT FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE " + COL_3 + " = Nitrates ";
```

or this

```
String query = "SELECT RESULT FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE TYPE = Nitrates";
```

neither work but this works just fine....

```
String query = "SELECT RESULT FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
```

so what gives with my where portion of it?

The Error I am getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT RESULT FROM testData_tableWHERE TYPE = Nitrates
```

Comment: if you would read the error carefully then you would know that you forget about space somewhere ... You seriously will be asking about every typo in your code on SO?

Comment: Thanks 10X! Why bother wasting your time responding if my question was so stupid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need whitespace between your table name and `WHERE`.
2. You need to put string literals in `'single quotes'`, or use `?` variable binding as in the example you have.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, when getting to learn Android they don't point out simple minor details, I did my best to format the statement as per the examples but I guess I overlooked that. i was using the ' ' previously but turns out it's that white space i was missing,